# SQL - STRING from TableA passed to TableB as INT

Tags: sql, arrays, string, integer

I have two tables, `TableA` and `TableB`.

- `TableA` has `ItemA` as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` = "1234,1235,1253,1643,2374".
- `TableB` has `ItemB` as `INT(MAX)`.

What I need is to pass the `STRING` from `TableA` to `TableB` and insert each element into a new row.

Is there a quicker method to do this instead of iterating through the `STRING` and comma separating?

I would pass it in as an Array or List but that cannot be done.

Comment: What **database system** are you using? *SQL* = *Structured Query Language* - a language, but not a product. Stuff like this is often vendor-specific, so we really need to know the exact database system (and version of it) that you're using

Comment: @marc_s Going to gueess MSSQL given `NVARCHAR`

Comment: @njk: sounds logical - but `INT(MAX)` ?!?!?!

Answer (score 0):

Using a CTE, the following should work:

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (
  ItemA nvarchar(max))

INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES ('1234,1235,1253,1643,2374')
```

**Query**

```
;WITH tmp(Item, ItemA) as (
    SELECT LEFT(ItemA, CHARINDEX(',',ItemA+',')-1),
        STUFF(ItemA, 1, CHARINDEX(',',ItemA+','), '')
    FROM tbl1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT LEFT(ItemA, CHARINDEX(',',ItemA+',')-1),
        STUFF(ItemA, 1, CHARINDEX(',',ItemA+','), '')
    FROM tmp
    WHERE ItemA > ''
)
INSERT INTO TableB (ItemB) SELECT Item FROM tmp
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8fc98/1)